# Why isn't my Firestore Security rule cascading downward?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I can't figure out how to write a Firestore rule that reflects: "when the user requests a doc from the `messages` collection, check that the doc above that "messages" collection includes a field thats an array which includes their uid. I've gotten the rule to work on the top level but if I try to access a document inside a collection, which is inside the "chats" collection, the user is denied.

Here's my relevant rule:

```
match /chats/{chatId}/{allChildren=**} {
  allow read, update: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.usersUids;
}
```

This works (the chatId doc has an array of uids):

`await db.collection("chats").doc(chatId).get()`

This does not work (none of the messages have an array of uids):

`await db.collection("chats").doc(chatId).collection("messages").get()`

It seems like the heart of the issue is that I'm trying to get the `resource.data` of the `messages` collection rather than the resource of the `chatId` doc, but I can't figure out to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resource` only contains the data from the specific document that was matched by the entire path.  It doesn't contain anything from any parent documents that appear in that path.

Any time you want to use fields from a document that wasn't matched by the full path, you have to `get()` the document using its own full path as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).  For example:

```
match /chats/{chatId}/{allChildren=**} {
  allow read, update: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(chatId)).data.usersUids;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Doug, this worked. Only thing I'd mention is that I also had to keep in the original rule: `allow read, update: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.usersUids` to cover my `.where` call across all chats.